# How to display average values in a row in place of null in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

| Row | urban_pop | med_age | migrants | fert_rate | landarea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | null | null | 570 |
| 2 | null | null | null | null | 640 |
| 3 | 23 | 30 | 35 | 13 | 450 |

I need to replace average values in place of null values in respective columns.

thank you

Comment: Do not use image, which column you are talking about? Where is age column? Sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that 
I have edited it, could you please check it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need select query then you can use the `avg` window function as follows:

```
Select coalesce(t.urban_pop, avg(t.urban_pop) over ()) as urban_pop,
       .... same for other columns
  From your_table t
```